# How to play audio in Dart application

Tags: dart, dart-html

Trying to play mp3 file using code:

```
playFile() {
audioContext = new AudioContext();
// get the audio file
return HttpRequest.request("short.mp3", responseType: "arraybuffer")
.then((HttpRequest request) {
  // decode it
  return audioContext.decodeAudioData(request.response)
.then((AudioBuffer buffer) {
    AudioBufferSourceNode source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connectNode(audioContext.destination);
    // play it now
    source.start(audioContext.currentTime);
  })
  .catchError((e) {print("error occurred in decode");});
});
}
```

The catchError clause is executed and mp3 does not play. I tried different variation of above code but no luck. I just cannot seem to get AudioBuffer from byte array using decodeAudioData call. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am using Dart version 1.8.5

Comment: changed mp3 to ogg format and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Must use .ogg format. mp3 does not work!

Comment: .mp3 does work but you need additional browser plugins.